# Is the NServiceBus RabbitMQ storage automatically the subscription storage?

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

Since RabbitMQ saves the subscriptions in the exchange routing, do you actually need to configure StorageType.Subscriptions' persistence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you want to use a different type of persistence...